# How to change parameters of pre-trained longformer model from huggingface

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using Hugging-face pre-trained `LongformerModel` model. I am using to extract embedding for sentence. I want to change the `token length`, `max sentence length` parameter but I am not able to do so. Here is the code.

```
model = LongformerModel.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096',output_hidden_states = True)
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

model.eval()

text=[" I like to play cricket"]

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text,max_length=20,padding=True,add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)

print(tokenizer.encode(text,max_length=20,padding=True,add_special_tokens=True))

# [0, 38, 101, 7, 310, 5630, 2]
```

**I expected encoder to give me list of size 20 with padding as I have passed a parameter `max_length=20.` But it returned list of size 7 only?**

```
attention_mask = torch.ones(input_ids.shape, dtype=torch.long, device=input_ids.device)
attention_mask[:, [0,-1]] = 2
outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, return_dict=True)

hidden_states = outputs[2]

print ("Number of layers:", len(hidden_states), "  (initial embeddings + 12 BERT layers)")
        layer_i = 0

print ("Number of batches:", len(hidden_states[layer_i]))
        batch_i = 0

print ("Number of tokens:", len(hidden_states[layer_i][batch_i]))
        token_i = 0

print ("Number of hidden units:", len(hidden_states[layer_i][batch_i][token_i]))
```

**Output:**

```
Number of layers: 13   (initial embeddings + 12 BERT layers)
Number of batches: 1
Number of tokens: 512 # How can I change this parameter to pick up my sentence length during run-time
Number of hidden units: 768
```

**How can I reduce number of tokens to sentence length instead of 512 ? Every-time I input a new sentence, it should pick up that length.**

Answer (score 1):

**Question regarding padding**

`padding=True` pads your input to the longest sequence. padding=`max_length` pads your input to the specified max_length ([documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.__call__)):

```py
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer

tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')
text=[" I like to play cricket"]
print(tokenizer.encode(text[0],max_length=20,padding='max_length',add_special_tokens=True))
```

Output:

```
[0, 38, 101, 7, 310, 5630, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Question regarding the number of tokens of the hidden states**

The Longformer implementation applies padding to your sequence to match the attention window sizes. You can see the size of the attention windows in your model config:

```py
model.config.attention_window
```

Output:

```
[512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
```

This is the corresponding code line: [link](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b1198a8440cc05f569b0bc22038993a1e5e707ab/src/transformers/models/longformer/modeling_longformer.py#L1652).